# Is there a way to create a line going from the marker on the timeline to the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/apcsqrgn/

Here is an example code showing the timeline, does someone know how to create a line going from the dot marker on the timeline to the text above it?
Thanks

might have something to do with this:

```
    $svg.circle = function (cx, cy, r, options) {
        var element = $(svg("circle"))
            .attr("cx", cx)
            .attr("cy", cy)
            .attr("r", r);
        setSvgOptions(element, options);
        return element;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you're trying to draw an additional vertical line from the black dots, to the labels directly above them like so:

[image]

To achieve this, you can call `$svg.line()` in the `drawEvent` function of your `Timeline` prototype the the following parameters and configuration:

```
    var newLine = $svg.line(
        x,                // Horizontal offset of the line being drawn
        this.height,      // Height is the vertical height of timeline
        x,                // Re-use "x" to achieve vertical line 
        this.height - 30) // 30 represents the height of newLine
    .attr("stroke", "#000000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .appendTo(group);     // Adds this newLine to the current svg group
```

For a working example, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/ygqw2a9j/

Comment: @MurderousKoala You bet :)